# Optimizing minHeap implementation

Tags: java, performance, homework, heap

I have implemented a java class for minHeap but it is not working as fast as I want . I want some help to change it to work faster in insertion or deleting the minimum node.

Here is my implementation:

```
public class MinHeap {
    private static final int d = 2;
    private int heapSize;
    private long[] heap;

    MinHeap(int capacity) {
        heapSize = 0;
        heap = new long[capacity + 1];
        Arrays.fill(heap, -1);
    }

    boolean isEmpty() {
        return heapSize == 0;
    }

    boolean isFull() {
        return heapSize == heap.length;
    }

    private int parent(int i) {
        return (i - 1) / d;
    }

    private int kthChild(int i, int k) {
        return d * i + k;
    }

    void insert(long x) {
        if (isFull())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Overflow Exception");
        heap[heapSize++] = x;
        bubbleUp(heapSize - 1);
    }

    long findMin() {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Underflow Exception");
        return heap[0];
    }

    void deleteMin() {
        delete(0);
    }

    void delete(int ind) {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Underflow Exception");
        heap[ind] = heap[heapSize - 1];
        heapSize--;
        bubbleDown(ind);
    }

    private void bubbleUp(int childInd) {
        long tmp = heap[childInd];
        while (childInd > 0 && tmp < heap[parent(childInd)]) {
            heap[childInd] = heap[parent(childInd)];
            childInd = parent(childInd);
        }
        heap[childInd] = tmp;
    }

    private void bubbleDown(int ind) {
        int child;
        long tmp = heap[ind];
        while (kthChild(ind, 1) < heapSize) {
            child = minChild(ind);
            if (heap[child] < tmp)
                heap[ind] = heap[child];
            else
                break;
            ind = child;
        }
        heap[ind] = tmp;
    }

    private int minChild(int ind) {
        int bestChild = kthChild(ind, 1);
        int k = 2;
        int pos = kthChild(ind, k);
        while ((k <= d) && (pos < heapSize)) {
            if (heap[pos] < heap[bestChild])
                bestChild = pos;
            pos = kthChild(ind, k++);
        }
        return bestChild;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for your comment, sorry I made a mistake, I had to delete the method maxElementIndex, It was related to the code I wrote for a special program, it is not in the minHeap implementation.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. How did you establish `minHeap [deleteMin() and insert() are] not working as fast as I want`? When in doubt, use a microbenchmarking framework. To check improvement suggestions, usage context, sample data or a test data generator would be useful.

Comment: (What about [java.util.PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)/[java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)?)

Comment: @greybeard I do not know what is the main problem, I'm implementing this for a homework assignment and I get two of the test cases as "time limit exceeded", I asked my teacher what is the reason and he said I can get a faster implementation of my minHeap. I have also tried PriorityQueue but still does not work:(

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, as suggested by greybeard  it would be useful posting  here test cases (input and output) indicating which ones ended with time limit exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information *what*, when asked for a reason for two "time limit exceeded" results, motivated your teacher to mention the possibility to "get" a faster *minHeap*, you deprive yourself of getting more useful answers. See [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436)
First and foremost, just *what* is the task timed?
I can't see anything seriously detrimental in your implementation:
I guess a bigger task than, say, handle a batch of *insertions* and *min extractions* gets timed, in need of an algorithmic improvement more likely than any tuning.

---

That said, there are principles like *YAGNI*, *KISS* and *DRY*.
Let me start with the bright side of *YAGNI* - You *Are* Gonna Need It:

- Documentation. The type that does *not* get separated from the code:
  [Documentation *in* the code](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide)

Otherwise, the code presented looks a pretty decent beginner's stab at coding a heap.
Catch:

- There are omissions from the *delete*s:
  • *not relevant when using an array of primitives as presented in the question*:
   Failing to set the reference at the index deallocated to something innocent (as `null`) does not immediately impede garbage collection, as it gets copied to a lower index. Enter the next *delete*…

  - bug in `delete(int d)`:
    It replaces element `atD` with `formerLast` and restores the heap relations in `formerLast` and its descendants.
    But what about its ancestors?
    Not to worry *if*
    1) it ends up at an index abode `d` *or*
    a) it was a descendant of `atD`: none of those has higher priority
    There are many ways to handle the situation -
    I'd prefer just dropping `delete(int d)` over just calling `bubbleUp()` or some elaborate handling trying to keep the number of comparisons low.

Room for improvement:

- Part of *Don't Repeat Yourself* is using interfaces:
  Define an `interface` for an, um, `PriorityCollection<E> extends Collection<E>`.
  One advantage is that implementations don't get to reduce visibility of interface methods like `isEmpty()`.
  Another is *inheriting* documentation, too.
  • have an `E extractTop()` return the top priority element it just removed from the Collection
  • nowadays, Java `interface`s can include *unit test code*, too.
- *Keep It Short&Simple* meets *You Ain't Gonna Need It* in fixing arity at 2:
  • simpler/shorter code
  • fixes a naming issue in `d` (maximal *d*egree?)
  • maximises information in relative position of keys
  • doesn't show in the interface, anyway

---

If and when competent (→ framework) measurements suggest the performance being a problem,
• consider returning to an array of *primitives*.
• *If* the cost of comparing elements is high, change tactics in *bubbleDown*(sink?): find the path along which to sink/bubble down, and look for elements that should stay in place starting from the bottom: this may almost half the number of comparisons.
• an `E replaceTop(E replacement)` may save considerable work
  it may be useful to additionally have the similar `E addAndExtractTop(E addition)`